# Can't get 'var express = require("express")' to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to js and I am trying to develop a simple node.js-mysql app. No matter what I do I can't get the standard

```
var express = require("express");
```

statement to work.

I have installed node.js and express correctly, express is in package.json. I have a local server running. But this simple line will not work.

On the node.js side at Windows command line I have no error but when I go to `localhost:3000` on the browser, I get

> 'Uncaught Error: Module name "express" has not been loaded yet for
> context: _. Use require([])' error at js console.

I tried changing it to

```
require(['express']`, function (express) {}
```

as suggested at node.js web site but then at the Windows command terminal I get a different error saying like

> 'expecting a string but received an array....'.

I have tried import instead of require and I have tried every suggestion that I could find on the Internet. I have been blowing my brains for weeks to get this to work with no success. I am so frustrated that I am seriously thinking about giving up all together. If someone can help I will be forever greatfull to him/her.

My main js code is as follows:

```js
var port = 3000;
// Import or load node.js dependency modules.
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));    // to support URL-encoded bodies.
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8887`);   
 });
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("D:/Behran's files/Web projects/havuzlusite/index.html"); 
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to run `main.js` in the browser using https://requirejs.org/ ?

Comment: I have installed requirejs and i am inluding it in my html as follows:

Comment: <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8887/require.js"></script>

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question but I simply go to my browser and enter localhost:3000 in the url box and hit ENTER,

Comment: That would be the problem then.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment. What would be the problem? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: My understanding from your comment is the the requirejs script tag in my html code. I have removed it and tried but now I am getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined' error at js console.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `require` in the JS you are running in the browser? See my *answer*.

Answer (score 0):

Require.JS is for loading AMD modules (and is, honestly, obsolete in today's JS landscape).

Node.js modules are either ECMAScript modules (which use `import` and `export`) or CommonJS modules (which use `require` and `module.exports`).

Even though both AMD and CommonJS modules use a function named `require` they are **not compatible**.

---

There are methods you can use to run ES modules and CommonJS modules in the browser **however** they can't replace APIs that are provided by runtimes.

Express.js needs to be able to listen for incoming HTTP requests. Browsers do not provide any mechanism to make that possible. Node.js does.

If you want to run Express.js you have to run it using Node.js and not a browser.

---

Express.js creates an HTTP server. A browser can make requests to it (e.g. if you type `http://127.0.0.1:3000` into the address bar.

(Your code says `server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8887` but the `port` constant is set to `3000`).

All your Express.js code must run through Node.js.

You can't send a copy of that code to the browser and run it there too.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful comments. I know very little so this may be a stupid question. I run my main js code in node.js at the Windows command line and it starts the server end. But this app also has a front end where user is supposed to click a button and enter login info. How is this going to be done if the browser cannot be used? When this app gets implemented, users will access it through a web site, they cannot be expected to run it in node.js command line like I do in the development environment.

Comment: I understand that the client side and node.js don't behave the same way and I cannot use node.js functions and methods on the client side. But if that is the case, how are the front end operations such as clicking a button and entering data going to be done on the node.js side? Sorry, I just started learning.

Comment: You make HTTP requests. Click links. Submit forms. Use Ajax.

Comment: I have also installed Browserify but it didn't help. As you suggested, I have also tried import instead of require but it led to a different error. I am assuming that node.js is still relatively new and there are many bugs and holes in terms of front end and server end talking to each other. But it is very frustrating.

Comment: You're wrong. For the front end and the back end to talk to each other, the front end (running in the browser) has to make HTTP requests (using links, forms, Ajax, etc) to the backend (running in Node.js). You can't make the backend run in the browser instead of in Node.js. Browserify or using import directly in the browser are only good for loading JS modules that are **designed to be front end code** in the browser. You can't use them to load **back end code** into the browser because it depends on APIs only provided by Node.js (as I said in the middle three paragraphs of my answer).

Comment: People have been using Node.js in production for about a decade. It is not new.

Comment: Ok. I now have to focus on learning Ajax. I have read about Ajax calls but I thought I could get away without them, it looks like I was wrong. Allow me to ask one more stupid question. When an http request is made by an Ajax call, will it display the login form on the browser where user can enter info and click submit? Again, thanks for your very valuable comments.

Comment: No. Ajax is the process of making an HTTP request with JavaScript and handling the response (also with JavaScript). It doesn't display anything. That is the responsibility of the code which creates the request and which handles the response.